# Trying to apply a selenium test on bootstrap modal using python

Tags: python, html, selenium, testing

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 id="add-title" class="modal-title">Add a text</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            </div>
            <section id="add-popup-card-body">
                <form id="add-form"><div class="sm-form modal-body">
<h6 id="add-popup-card-body-subtitle" class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Please enter text</h6>
<input type="text" id="add-input-form" class="sm-form modal-body form-control validate" pattern="\S+" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="32" placeholder="tag" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" required="">
<div><small>*Spaces are not allowed</small></div>
</div>`enter code here`
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</div></form>
            </section>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All that I need is to find a way to make Selenium test close the modal. I have tried these so far and none worked:

```py
self.driver.findElement(By.className("close")).click()
```

```py
self.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'close']")).click()
```

```py
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="close"]').click()
```

Comment: What url and errors occur?

Comment: ..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:247: ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: @David : Check out the solution given below, and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal' and text()='×']
```

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal' and text()='×']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal' and text()='×']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal' and text()='×']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal' and text()='×']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.close[data-dismiss='modal']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal'][text()='×']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, as the desired element is a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.close[data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal'][text()='×']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have tried all the above solution but none worked. I was getting similar errors. After some reading I called an id that was above the "modal-content" and added 3 div . By using this code :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='add-tag popup']/div/div/div/button").click()
```